# Variance of $X$ and Variance of $\log(X)$. How to relate them?

Tags: variance, lognormal-distribution

I have the variance of a random variable $X$ and I want to obtain the variance of $\log(X)$. Is it possible if I dont know its PDF?
If I assume that $X$ has a lognormal PDF, how variances should be related?

Comment: Because the variance of any positive multiple $\sigma X$ is $\sigma^2$ times the variance of $X,$ but the variance of $\log(\sigma X) = \log(\sigma)+\log(X)$ does not change, it is impossible in general to say anything about the relationship between the variance of $X$ and that of $\log(X).$ Indeed, it's even possible for either one or both of those variances to be infinite. As an example, for $t\ge 1$ let $\Pr(\log(X)\le -t) = 1/t:$ this logarithm has infinite variance, but $X$ itself (being confined to the interval $(0,1]$) has finite variance.

Answer (score 12):

The delta method is pretty useful here. Using a first order Taylor series approximation about the mean of $X$
$$
\log(X) \approx \log(E[X]) + \frac{(X-E[X])}{E[X]}
$$
so, after we take expectations and variances on both sides,

- $E[\log(X)] \approx \log(E[X])$
- $V[\log(X)] \approx E[X]^{-2}\text{V}[X]$.

This relates to the idea of [variance-stabilization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346022/variance-stabilizing-transformation/346050#346050); if a dependent variable in a regression has a variance that is proportional to the mean squared, then taking the log of that dependent variable produces something that has constant variance, which is often a desirable or necessary assumption.

Comment: Could you please show how you derive the approximation for $\text{log}(X)$? Thank you!

Comment: For $E[X]^{-2}$, did you mean the second moment or the expected value of $X^2$?

Answer (score 3):

**Comment** on lognormal and normal distributions.

The variance of data tends to decrease when you take logs of the values.
Perhaps the most common case is that, if $X_1$ is lognormal, then $X_2 = \ln(X_1)$ is normal, which has smaller variance than $X_.1$ Also, if it exists, $X_3 = \ln(X_2)$ may have a still smaller variance.

Below we begin with a random sample (using R) of $n = 10^4$ observations
from a lognormal distribution with parameters $\mu = 50, \sigma = 2.$ (It is customary to use lognormal parameters that match parameters of the related normal distribution. You can look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) on 'lognormal distributions' for details.) We show means and standard deviations for distributions of $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3.$

```
set.seed(720); n = 10^4
x2 = rnorm(n, 50, 2);  x1 = exp(x2);  x3 = log(x2)
mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x3)
[1] 3.686093e+22
[1] 50.01289         # aprx E(X2) = 50
[1] 3.911481
sd(x1); sd(x2); sd(x3)
[1] 2.308712e+23
[1] 1.997261         # aprx SD(X2) = 2
[1] 0.04004551
```

Then we show histograms of the three samples. At the left, notice that it
is difficult to make an informative histogram of $X_1$ because it is so
severely skewed to the right. In the center panel, we overlay the density
function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu =50, \sigma=2);$ which is symmetrical.
At the right, notice that taking (natural) logs once again results in a
slightly left-skewed distribution.

[image]

*Notes:* (1) The the support of a lognormal distribution is $(0, \infty).$
A normal distribution may take negative values. If the lognormal distribution is truncated to $(1, \infty)$ so that the normal distribution is truncated to $(0,\infty),$ then the natural log of that "normal" distribution exists. The distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(50, 2)$ has almost no probability below $0,$ so the truncation would have little practical effect in this example.

(2) R code for the figure above:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(x1, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
hist(x2, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x,50,2), add=T, col="red")
hist(x3, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

(3) However, it is *not always true* that taking logs gives a smaller variance. If $X_2 \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),\, X_1 = e^{X_2},$ and
$X_3 = \ln(X_2),$ then R code similar to the code for the lognormal example gives the following results:

```
set.seed(720); n = 10^5
x2 = runif(n);  x1 = exp(x2);  x3 = log(x2)
var(x1); var(x2); var(x3)
[1] 0.2411124
[1] 0.08316279  # aprx V(X2) = 1/12
[1] 1.01091
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! I would suggest that in (3) we do not need to form $X_1$. Just $X_2$ and $X_3$ are enough for the argument.