# How should I deduce the variance and expectation of the log of a variable?

Tags: variance, expected-value, biostatistics, approximation

I read this paper ["voom: precision weights unlock linear model analysis tools for RNA-seq read counts"](http://www.statsci.org/smyth/pubs/VoomPreprint.pdf), in the methods, the "Delta rule for log-cpm" section:

The RNA-seq data consist of a matrix of read counts $r_{gi}$, for RNA samples $i=1$ to $n$, and genes $g=1$ to $G$. Write $R_i$ for the total number of mapped reads for sample $i$:
$$R_i=\sum_{g=1}^{G}r_{gi}$$ They define the log-counts per million (log-cpm) value for each count as: $$y_{gi}=\log_2\left(\frac{r_{gi}+0.5}{R_i+1}\times 10^6\right)$$

Write $\lambda=E(r)$ for the expected value of a read count given the experimental conditions, and suppose that: $$\text{Var}(r)=\lambda+\phi\lambda^2$$ If $r$ is large, then the log-cpm value of the observation is: $$y\approx\log_2(r)-\log_2(R)+6\log_2(10)$$ where $R$ is the library size. The analysis is conditional on $R$, so $R$ is treated as a constant. It follows that $\text{Var}(y)\approx \text{Var}(\log_2 r)$. If $\lambda$ also is large, then:
$$(\log_2 r)(\ln 2)\approx \ln r \approx \ln\lambda+\frac{r-\lambda}{\lambda}$$ so $$\text{Var}(y)(\ln 2)^2\approx\frac{\text{Var}(r)}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda}+\phi$$
How should I deduce the last 2 equations?

Comment: There are a couple of "log 2" factors in the last 2 displays (one with subscripted 2) that I think you meant to represent the natural log of 2. It might be easier to read this if you explicitly wrote `ln` for the natural log where that's intended.

Comment: Yes you are right, it seems the author changed the online version recently. I updated these equations. Thanks

Comment: I suspect this is a case where someone did some math and didn't pay attention to the numerical implications of the result.   Let's look at the first of your equations; assume $\lambda = 100$ ("large") and $r \approx \lambda$.  Then $\lambda + (r-\lambda)/\lambda \approx \lambda$ and $\log_2(r) \approx \log_2(\lambda)$, so we have $\log_2(100) \approx 100$.  Making $\lambda$ larger won't help.  Even if we make $r =$, say, $2\lambda$ or $\lambda/2$, we don't get anything like "approximately equal to".

Comment: There is an updated version and these equations had been corrected. http://www.statsci.org/smyth/pubs/VoomPreprint.pdf  I updated my question to the updated equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the corrected version of the equations, this follows from a standard approximation to the variance of a natural log of a random variable, given the variance of the random variable. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/418313/28500), along with its warnings about when this approximation might get you into trouble.

Work first with the natural log of $r$. The [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\ln r$ about the mean value $\lambda$ for $r$ is:

$$ \ln r \approx \ln \lambda + \frac{(r-\lambda)}{\lambda} - \frac{(r-\lambda)^2}{2\lambda^2}+\dots,$$

based on the first and second derivatives of the natural log function at $r=\lambda$. The terms after the first two are assumed to become small with large $\lambda$.

Then continue by taking the expectations of both sides. As $\lambda$ is the mean of $r$, the expectation of the second term is 0, leaving:

$$E[\ln r] \approx \ln E[r].$$

Now, working with the first two terms of the Taylor expansion, take the variance of both sides, the expected value of squared deviations from the mean:

$$\text{Var}(\ln r) \approx E\left[\left(\ln \lambda + \frac{(r-\lambda)}{\lambda} -  \ln E[r]\right)^2\right]$$

$E[r]$ is $\lambda$, so the first and third terms within the parentheses on the right cancel, leaving:

$$\text{Var}(\ln r)\approx E\left[ \left(\frac{(r-\lambda)}{\lambda} \right)^2\right]=\frac{\text{Var }r}{\lambda^2}.$$

Given the assumed form for the variance of $r$, the rightmost part of the last display immediately follows. The $\ln 2$ factors translate between the natural log and the $\log_2$ scales.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Taylor expansions for the moments of functions of random variables](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables)
$$
\begin{align}
\log X & = \log (\mu_X+X-\mu_X) \\
&\approx \log (\mu_X)+ \log' (\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)+\frac{1}{2}\log''(\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)^2 \\
&\approx\log (E(X))+\frac{X-E(X)}{E(X)}
\end{align}
$$ so take expectations and variances on both sides,

$$E(\log X)\approx\log (E(X))$$
$$\text{Var}(\log X)\approx E\left[\frac{X-E(X)}{E(X)}\right]^2=\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{(E(X))^2}$$
So

$$E[\log r]\approx\log (\lambda)+\frac{r-\lambda}{\lambda}
$$

$$\text{Var}[\log r]\approx\frac{\text{Var}(r)}{\lambda^2}
$$